# Python. Не видит значение переменной при выводе функции a * b

Tags: python

я только начал программировать на python и возникла проблема:

```
x - int(input("Введите первое число:"))
y - int(input("Введите второе число:"))

def sum(a,b):
    return a * b

sum(x,y)
```

при попытке открыть файл выводится надпись:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/www/Downloads/Функция.py", line 1, in <module>
    x - int(input("Введите первое число:"))
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: логично, ведь переменная `x` нигде не объявлена

Comment: `x = int(input("Введите первое число:")) ` ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код, отступы разъехались и код перестал быть рабочим

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставьте вместо `-` присваивание `=` и всё заработает.

```
x = int(input("Введите первое число:"))
y = int(input("Введите второе число:"))

def sum(a,b):
    return a * b

sum(x,y)
```